# Grafanalib: Dashboard Pushing Showing Issue

Tags: grafana

Using Grafanalib to push dashboards to grafana.
Grafana Version : 6.7.3
Grafanalib Versiob: 0.7.0

I am pushing dashboard into grafana using grafanalib. It shows unexpected error ans shows [image]

Even when i use example dashboard given in grafanalibs doc the same issue is occurring. When i try the same on grafana version 9.x its working there.

require help to solve this issue.

Comment: Most likely api had breaking changes over 3 major versions.